# Username and Password verification not working in Java GUI Project with getText() and getter/setter methods?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, authentication

I'm using an if/else series of statements to verify that the user input is the same, using the .equals() method. However, it seems that even though I put the same input into the "Create Account" frame's TextField and PasswordField, as well as the "Login" frame's TextField and PasswordField, the Dialog Box pops up saying "Invalid login info, try again". What am I doing wrong?

**Create Account Class/Frame**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CreateAccount extends JFrame{

    private JLabel user, pass; //label next to username and password field
    private JTextField username; //enter username
    private JPasswordField password; //enter password
    private JButton create;
    private String u, p;
    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 300;

    public CreateAccount(){


        setTitle("Create Account");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);

        createView();
        setVisible(true);

    }


    private void createView(){


        JPanel panelMain = new JPanel(null);
        getContentPane().add(panelMain);

        user = new JLabel("Username: ");
        panelMain.add(user);
        user.setBounds(50, 30, 120, 25);

        username = new JTextField();
        panelMain.add(username);
        username.setBounds(140, 30, 150, 25);


        pass = new JLabel("Password: ");
        panelMain.add(pass);
        pass.setBounds(50, 100, 120, 25);

        password = new JPasswordField();
        panelMain.add(password);
        password.setBounds(140, 100, 150, 25);

        create = new JButton("Create");
        panelMain.add(create);
        create.setBounds(170, 180, 100,25);
        create.addActionListener((new Listener()));

    }

    private class Listener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String usn = username.getText();
            String psd = password.getText();
            setUser(usn);
            setPass(psd);
            new Login();
            setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    public void setUser(String usn){
        this.u = usn;
    }

    public String getUser(){
        return u;
    }

    public void setPass(String psd){
        this.p = psd;
    }

    public String getPass(){
        return p;
    }

}
```

**Login Class/Frame**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Login extends JFrame{

    private JLabel user, pass;
    private JTextField username;
    JPasswordField password;
    private JButton login;
    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 300;


    public Login(){

        setTitle("Login");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        createView();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    private void createView(){

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);
        getContentPane().add(panel);

        user = new JLabel("Username: ");
        panel.add(user);
        user.setBounds(50, 30, 120, 25);

        username = new JTextField();
        panel.add(username);
        username.setBounds(140, 30, 150, 25);

        pass = new JLabel("Password: ");
        panel.add(pass);
        pass.setBounds(50, 100, 120, 25);

        password = new JPasswordField();
        panel.add(password);
        password.setBounds(140, 100, 150, 25);

        login = new JButton("Login");
        panel.add(login);
        login.setBounds(170, 170, 100, 25);
        login.addActionListener((new Listener()));
    }

    private class Listener implements ActionListener{
        CreateAccount grab = new CreateAccount();
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String usn = username.getText();
            String psd = password.getText();

            if(usn.equals("Admin") && psd.equals("Password")){

                new AdminDB();
            }

            else if (usn.equals(grab.getUser()) && psd.equals(grab.getPass()))
            {
                new UserDB();
            }

            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid login info, try again");
            }

            setVisible(false);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are inputting `Admin` and not `admin` or `ADMIN` ?

Comment: It works for the Admin input, but not for the 2nd else if statement where the user creates their own username and password, and then logs in with their own username and password.

Comment: You aren't saving the username/password any where.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Also consider to `trim`  your input Strings

Comment: `CreateAccount` shouldn't be creating a new instance `Login`, instead, you should be using modal dialogs, so that when `CreateLogin` completes, the instance of `Login` which called it can determine what the values are

Comment: Oh boy, I've been called out, guess I've got some StackOverflow etiquette to learn. Thank you all for your input, I will try to figure out a new solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to know where to start, but, basically, your classes are sharing information between them.

To make things little easier, you should be using modal dialogs to gather user input of this type, see [How to use dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details.

Basically, this will stop the execution of your code at the point at which the dialog is made visible and continue execution when it's closed.

In this way, you can interrupt the flow of your program, gather some information and continue when it's done.

The following example basically reimplements your code using dialogs instead, one of the key points is way down in the `Login` `Listener`...

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Register")) {
      CreateAccount createAccount = new CreateAccount(Login.this);
      credentials = createAccount.getCredentials();
    } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Login")) {
```

Here, when the <kbd>Register</kbd> button is clicked, the `CreateAccount` dialog is presented, BUT, the code won't continue until AFTER the dialog is closed, at which time it gets the user `Credentials` which can then used to login.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
  }

  public Test() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Login login = new Login();
      }
    });
  }

  public class Credentials {

    private String userName, password;

    public Credentials(String userName, String password) {
      this.userName = userName;
      this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
      return userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
      return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Credentials{" + "userName=" + userName + ", password=" + password + '}';
    }

  }

  public class CreateAccount extends JDialog {

    private JLabel user, pass; //label next to username and password field
    private JTextField username; //enter username
    private JPasswordField password; //enter password
    private JButton create;

    private Credentials credentials;

    public CreateAccount(JDialog owner) {
      super(owner, true);
      setTitle("Create Account");
      createView();
      pack();
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setVisible(true);

    }

    private void createView() {

      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;

      user = new JLabel("Username: ");
      add(user, gbc);

      gbc.gridy++;
      pass = new JLabel("Password: ");
      add(pass, gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 1;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      username = new JTextField(10);
      add(username, gbc);

      gbc.gridy++;
      password = new JPasswordField(10);
      add(password, gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy++;
      gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
      create = new JButton("Create");
      add(create, gbc);
      create.addActionListener(new Listener());
    }

    private class Listener implements ActionListener {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String usn = username.getText();
        String psd = password.getText();

        credentials = new Credentials(usn, psd);

        dispose();
      }
    }

    public Credentials getCredentials() {
      return credentials;
    }

  }

  public class Login extends JDialog {

    private JLabel user, pass;
    private JTextField username;
    JPasswordField password;
    private JButton login;

    private Credentials credentials;

    public Login() {
      setModal(true);
      createView();
      setTitle("Login");
      pack();
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setVisible(true);

    }

    private void createView() {

      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;

      user = new JLabel("Username: ");
      add(user, gbc);

      gbc.gridy++;
      pass = new JLabel("Password: ");
      add(pass, gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 1;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      username = new JTextField(10);
      add(username, gbc);

      gbc.gridy++;
      password = new JPasswordField(10);
      add(password, gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy++;
      login = new JButton("Login");
      add(login, gbc);
      login.addActionListener((new Listener()));

      gbc.gridx++;
      JButton register = new JButton("Register");
      add(register, gbc);
      register.addActionListener((new Listener()));
    }

    private class Listener implements ActionListener {

//    CreateAccount grab = new CreateAccount();
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Register")) {
          CreateAccount createAccount = new CreateAccount(Login.this);
          credentials = createAccount.getCredentials();
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Login")) {
          String usn = username.getText();
          String psd = password.getText();

          if (usn.equals("Admin") && psd.equals("Password")) {
            System.out.println("Admin");
            dispose();
          } else if (credentials != null && credentials.getUserName().equals(usn) && credentials.getPassword().equals(psd)) {
            System.out.println("user");
            dispose();
          } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Login.this, "Invalid login info, try again");
          }

        }
      }
    }

  }

}
```

A better, long term solution would be to store the credentials in some kind of database or lookup which can be retrieved between runs.

And finally...don't use `null` layouts!

[image: All the reasons why you shouldn't use null layouts]

The above is you unmodified code running on my PC, nuff said

Comment: Wow thank you so much for the feedback, I truly appreciate it. I was unaware of dialogs.